# Настройка GitHub actions или travis-ci

Tags: golang, github, travis-ci

Есть репозиторий 
https://github.com/LazarenkoA/prometheus_1C_exporter

подключил к нему actions и travis-ci и все падает (actions на этапе получения зависимостей, travis-ci с такой ошибкой "The command "go get -t -v ./..." failed and exited with 1 during."), поделитесь рабочим конфигом. 
Даже если просто взять конфиг travis такой language: go, все равно падает

сейчас конфиг travis такой

```
language: go
go:
  - tip

before_install:
  - go get -t -v ./...

after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Comment: `-v ./...` - это что такое?

Comment: честно, не знаю )) я конфиг взял у кого-то из репы. Без этого тоже не работает